# How to build out docker engine arm binary?

Tags: docker, arm

I see [this](https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/aarch64/), from here I can download `docker daemon` & `docker client` for arm64 version which works.

```
$ ls | xargs file
containerd:      ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, Go BuildID=qw3vidR0_xw6ad6RsQMc/1Mvy0xkskqC4LJM8ekEq/jvzo407uWVjZxA71fYmB/r1PXwIjd2b3xjPt0tOPD, BuildID[sha1]=f8a87e57a37d283060789f7b6b967f35c30d1385, stripped
containerd-shim: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=-FbKcwS7GH0h3bDWjYhL/LdkbOXrZDB7bUI5hVare/0n0703v40o5qYAvXmWf7/2_QBPVlcfCHqgmApuCcj, stripped
ctr:             ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, Go BuildID=wcFfUczubU9WzSMgMHbV/9qJT0yqeUUvOvoLwk2rL/UJPlPmjhWvWQSGM0BjUq/nz-x_U4rhoAErNC5UKvE, BuildID[sha1]=e7fe6b82894b6bf6c70a2427481f879a5c342cbd, stripped
docker:          ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=kGbyf6df_lIBsP2zN-aw/mSkNZi8-n573BH3qCxiL/S_qDX39Bbfl6h9BHKaHC/quZgsL-4q_5_Xu6VnCVI, not stripped
dockerd:         ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, Go BuildID=W3bAmk2RFppITPWcS_4m/ODbBAFymPAKdThBEapBo/FEH4KbWqvMFNQhWUKSp1/QA_f4aqjz6iKiFCV3joT, BuildID[sha1]=96792f1bae1750c4b9fc949c8988694b7378b80e, with debug_info, not stripped
docker-init:     ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=dd417538230515ff4846537c0332512632db5bd2, stripped
docker-proxy:    ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=e1uObKFCO2MCzLXoZ4ij/IWuhN_VlndZn0XCvmPYQ/SqEk5FGxOKYjp8b-3-WP/Y_RNFD3JSDFXbk_neaAl, with debug_info, not stripped
runc:            ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, Go BuildID=QhVg0N-9Q2OEb5Lj-BN1/HxEuk0yZiGKQguwkToc9/EBT3VcPRTQwVA_0eTS1l/sXiMljveurc6-0yOOwdh, BuildID[sha1]=209a7edb91edbd565b7f90f0c57bc11ba29ea9a9, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Then, I want to know how above binary comes out, I see [this](https://ops.tips/blog/compiling-your-own-forked-docker-release/), it's a good article which I successfully build out binary for x86-64 with `make static DOCKER_BUILD_PKGS=static-linux` with the source [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce)

But, I need arm version, so I tried next 2 methods:

1. `make static DOCKER_BUILD_PKGS="static-linux cross-arm"`
2. `GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 make static DOCKER_BUILD_PKGS=static-linux`

Above 2 methods both work to build out `docker client` with `arm` version, but the `docker daemon` still `x86-64` version, see next:

```
orange@orange:~/docker-ce/components/packaging/static/build/linux/docker$ ls | xargs file
containerd:      ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b3373a479eb94f19270cd9db5b27c149dfc58b9c, stripped
containerd-shim: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
ctr:             ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=78dba144a5f3d9c4f1d6588e4d96b8dc84531860, stripped
docker:          ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
dockerd:         ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=bc15506d7c7e9cf25a854ef6296940821769949a, not stripped
docker-init:     ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=935ade6a155bf37269208cfb807f9d6653f34020, stripped
docker-proxy:    ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
runc:            ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=14523b67ee2ca600894e06729f8606f5a7d0e227, not stripped
```

So, what I am doing wrong, how could I get arm version for dockerd?

Answer (score 1):

From the source code we can see the cross-arm option does the client only.

https://github.com/docker/docker-ce-packaging/blob/753db553b261ffd84e2d452a0eff1aade6b30bf3/static/Makefile

Try to build on a ARM64 VM like ec2.

Comment: You are correct, this is the reason I just get arm client. But how they make this, like here: https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/aarch64/ ? And it seems finally it will  `set up a docker container` which prebuilt build toolchains in the container to build the code, so what added if I build in an arm vm? Is there any 
 chance I find a wrong git repo to build it out?

Comment: You are right, once the client binary is produced via docker container, it seems the following commands are used to get tgz file from the build folder                                                                                                                                          mkdir -p build/arm/docker
cp $(CLI_DIR)/build/docker-linux-arm build/arm/docker/docker
tar -C build/arm -c -z -f build/arm/docker-$(STATIC_VERSION).tgz docker                I thought you were asking for dockerd.